# Is it possible to set up an AWS API Gateway endpoint for a Lambda function, using the AWS API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am exposing a AWS Lambda function to public HTTP requests by setting up an AWS API Gateway endpoint pointing to it.

There are two parts to this:

- Create and upload my AWS Lambda function
- Set up the API Gateway to point a HTTP endpoint to my Lambda function

I want to do both parts using API calls instead of the web interface. I can do that for the first part using the AWS SDK and AWS CLI.

However, for the second part, I'm stuck. I haven't found a mention of the API Gateway when looking through the [AWS SDK for node.js](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-node-js/), or the [AWS CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/)

Is there a way to set up an API Gateway endpoint for a Lambda function, programatically using the AWS API?

Comment: CLI / SDK support for `API Gateway` is not ready yet. I personally expect more details about these features to be published at `re:Invent 2015`.

Comment: Also, `CloudFormation` is something that may very well help you in your future efforts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it's possible via AWS's API to set up your Amazon API Gateway endpoints for your AWS Lambda functions.

While the AWS SDK for JavaScript in Node.js and AWS CLI haven't supported Amazon API Gateway yet, you can set up them using [Amazon API Gateway REST API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/) without official SDK. In this case, you will probably use these APIs:

1. restapi:create
2. resource:create
3. method:put
4. integration:put
5. integrationresponse:put
6. methodresponse:put

You might want to use 3rd party libraries to integrate Amazon API Gateway with AWS Lambda such as [jaws-stack/JAWS](https://github.com/jaws-stack/JAWS) or [r7kamura/fluct](https://github.com/r7kamura/fluct).

Answer (score 3):

Yes...it is absolutely possibly.  Below is some node.js code that uses the AWS-SDK for node.js.  I'm doing a POST here for the method integration.  Now there are a few things you'll need.  Hope this helps...good luck!

> The ResourceId of the Method you're using for the Gateway API
>
> The Gateway API Rest Id
>
> The ARN of the Invoke Role that is able to invoke your Lambda Function
>
> The ARN of the Lambda function you want to integrate.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

api = new AWS.APIGateway(); 

var params = {
    httpMethod: 'POST',
    resourceId: [YOUR RESOURCE ID],
    restApiId: [YOUR REST API ID],
    type: 'AWS',
    uri: [YOUR LAMBDA FUNCTION ARN],
    integrationHttpMethod: 'POST',
    credentials : [YOUR INVOKE ROLE ARN]
};

api.putIntegration(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('AWS Error', err);
    } else {
        console.log('Put Integration Method Created', data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin! The uri was not easy to figure out, so here is a more detailed description in case it helps someone: --uri arn:aws:apigateway:aws-region:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:aws-region:aws-acct-id:function:your-lambda-function-name/invocations

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's doable.

JAWS project has a nice and simple js implementation, and it works pretty well
https://github.com/jaws-stack/jaws-api-gateway-client

Also the latest AWS CLI (version 1.99) has supported API Gateway fully. 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/index.html#cli-aws-apigateway

Answer (score 0):

You can point your API endpoint to a Lambda Function. While creating new HTTP method in API Gateway, select "Integration type" as "Lambda Function", then select the Lambda function you need to invoke.

Main challenge would be mapping the API input parameters to the Lambda model object, you can either define the mapping manually or provide a model schema(uses [json-schema](http://json-schema.org/)).

Example mapping:

```
{
    "firstname" : "$input.params('firstname')",
    "lastname"  : "$input.params('lastname')"
}
```

Refer [this blog](http://www.texient.com/2016/02/java-building-restful-microservices-with-aws-lambda-and-api-gateway.html) post for step-by-step tutorial written for Java 8.